# Trying to convert some PHP array code to VB.NET

Tags: php, vb.net, arrays

**EDIT**

Ok, so after working through this for a while, I've come up with a solution that works, and it's cleaner than I had originally thought up for it. Thanks for the help guys. Here's the code.

```vb
Function Program_Search() As String()
    'An ArrayList of Objects containing strings for each row.
    'So the result is ArrayList(objRow1(strID, strPrograms), objRow2(strID, strPrograms).. etc)
    Dim program_results As ArrayList = Get_Results("SELECT ID, Programs FROM tbMetrics ORDER BY ID ASC", strConnectionString)

    'Initialize the list of programs. This will contian the tbMetrics Programs that match the selected Program name.
    Dim programs As ArrayList = New ArrayList

    'Loop through each row selected
    For Each row As Object In program_results
        'Not currently used.
        Dim strID As String = row(0).ToString

        'An integer representation of a binary number. Each digit represents a different program being checked.
        Dim intPrograms As Integer = CInt(row(1).ToString)

        'Convert number to binary string (reversed)
        Dim strReversed As String = StrReverse(Convert.ToString(intPrograms, 2))

        'Loop through each of the programs in the drop down box which should contain all of the possible choices in order.
        For index As Integer = 0 To ddlPrograms.Items.Count - 1
            'A bit of an ugly if state that checks for a 1 in the binary position for the selected program.
            'Then if it's selected, it checks that the program matches the one selected by the user.
            'Finally, it makes sure it doesn't add the same number to the array.
            If (strReversed.Length - 1) >= index _
                And strReversed(index) = "1" _
                And ddlPrograms.SelectedValue.ToString = ddlPrograms.Items(index).Value.ToString _
                And programs.Contains(intPrograms) = False Then

                'If it passes all of the above checks, then finally add the program integer to the arraylist.
                programs.Add(intPrograms)
            End If
        Next index
    Next row

    'Return the list of programs as an array, to be used with SQL IN().
    Return programs.ToArray
End Function
```

**END EDIT**

**ORIGINAL BELOW**

Ok, so I'm a PHP programmer, trying to learn some VB.NET. Arrays greatly confuse me in VB.NET, so I wrote some example code in PHP the way I know how to do it. I would greatly appreciate it if someoen could show me the proper way it would work in VB.NET.

```
<?php

function get_result() {
    $result = query("SELECT id, value FROM test_table");
    /*Returned as:
    array(
      array("id1", "value1"), 
      array("id2", "value2")...etc.
    )*/

    $haystack_top = array();

    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $id = $row[0]; //Not used currently
        $value = $row[1];

        for($i=0; $i <= $value; $i++) {
            if (check_value($i)) {
                $haystack_value = get_new_value($i);
                $haystack_top[$value][] = $haystack_value;
            }
        }
    }

    $needle = get_needle();

    $result = array();

    foreach ($haystack_top as $value=>$haystack) {
        if (in_array($needle, $haystack)) {
            $result[] = $value;
        }
    }

    return array_unique($result);
}

?>
```

Here's an older, unfinished copy of what I've been working on in Vb.NET It's not in the form I actually need because I changed how the logic should work while building the PHP example, but it shows the confusion I ran into with Arrays in VB.NET.

```vb
Function Program_Search() As String()
    Dim program_results As Object = Get_Results("SELECT ID, Programs FROM tbMetrics ORDER BY ID ASC", strConnectionString)

    'Create an array of strings to fill with potential field results.
    Dim fields As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()

    For Each row As Object In program_results
        Dim strID As String = row(0).ToString
        Dim strPrograms As String = row(1).ToString

        Dim intPrograms As Integer = CInt(strPrograms)

        'Convert number to binary string (reversed)
        Dim strReversed As String = StrReverse(Convert.ToString(intPrograms, 2))

        For index As Integer = 0 To ddlPrograms.Items.Count - 1
            If (strReversed.Length - 1) >= index Then
                If strReversed(index) = "1" Then
                    fields.Add(ddlPrograms.Items(index).Value.ToString)
                End If
            End If
        Next index
    Next row

    Dim programs As String() = fields.ToArray

    Dim results As String()

    If programs.Contains(ddlPrograms.SelectedValue.ToString) Then

    End If

    Return programs
End Function
```

Because someone was curious about the Get_Results function here's the code for that.

```vb
'Runs the passed query and returns each row as an object within an ArrayList
    Function Get_Results(ByVal query As String, ByVal ConnectionStringName As String) As ArrayList
        Dim sqlComm As Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand = Get_Connection(query, ConnectionStringName)

        'Open that connection
        sqlComm.Connection.Open()

        'Execute the query and store all of the results into the SqlDataReader.
        Dim sqlRead As Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader = sqlComm.ExecuteReader()

        Dim result As ArrayList = New ArrayList

        'Read each row one by one.
        While sqlRead.Read()
            'Create an object of the size needed.
            Dim row(sqlRead.FieldCount - 1) As Object

            'Fill the row object with the values.
            sqlRead.GetValues(row)

            'Add the result object to the array.
            result.Add(row)
        End While

        'Close all open connections to the database.
        sqlRead.Close()
        sqlComm.Connection.Close()

        Return result
    End Function
```

Comment: What have you tried and what's not working in what you tried?  What part of all that code are you having trouble with duplicating in VB?  Is it the fact that it's a 2D array that is causing you grief?

Comment: @SteveDog I've edited the question to kind of show where I was on VB.NET code before getting frusturated and writing the PHP example code to help me work through it logically, and know what I needed exactly.

Comment: What is the signature of the Get_Results method you are calling?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by signature, but it returns an object with with sub-objects for each row in the database, and sub-sub-objects with each field in that row.  
  
So basically Object(Row(Field,Field),Row(Field,Field))

Comment: Thanks.  So, what part of your Program_Search method are you having trouble with?  It would be helpful if you could reduce the lines of code to just the ones that are pertinent to your question and explain what about those lines you are having trouble with.

Comment: to be honest, I'm just confused how to properly create dynamic multi-dimensional arrays in VB.NET, and how to use them like I do in my PHP example. I always use my arrays in languages like PHP and javascript, so I'm more used to the way they handle them. Statically typed languages, and especially VB.NET have me a bit lost on this. Thanks for all the help so far, just talking through it alone is helping :-)

Comment: I understand you're confused, and I'd be happy to help.  I just still don't get what it is you are confused about.  It seems like the code to posted is working.  Or at least the parts having to do with arrays seem to work.  So is it just that you don't understand why it works that way?  If you are new to strongly typed languages, I would put Option Strict On at the top of your code files (or better yet, turn it on for the whole project in the project properties).  That will force you to do things properly and cast your type conversions.

Comment: I wish they would just change Option Strict to be on by default and change it so you have to type `Option Dufus On` to turn it off, but that's just me.

Comment: @SteveDog +1 for Option Dufus

Comment: Whoever down-voted the question, please explain to Ryan why it was down-voted. He's new (obviously) and would benefit in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this comment "...to be honest, I'm just confused how to properly create dynamic multi-dimensional arrays in VB.NET, and how to use them like I do in my PHP example...", I'll provide my answer.

Your line:

```
 Dim fields As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
```

creates a list, not an array. Lists are a bit easier to use as you can add items without having to resize. You could make a `List(Of MyObject)` if you would like to do that instead of a 2D array. Just create a class with two fields and make a list of those objects. Your class would be about 4 lines of code.

To create a 2D array, which is what it looks like you're doing, you should find everything you need here.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2de1t93(v=vs.90).aspx

Unfortunately, to create a dynamic 2D array, there's no streamline way to do that. You have to copy the elements over to another array, if I'm not mistaken. It's pretty lame, I know. That's why I like the `List(Of MyObject)` approach in that you can just `MyList.Add(myObject)` when you create a new item.

If you need to iterate through the items later to retrieve the values, you can just use a for-loop and access them as such:

```
MyList(i).MyObjectPropertyName1
MyList(i).MyObjectPropertyName2
```

VB.NET is probably one of the more readable languages, but with any, you have to get used to it. I looked at your PHP and my head almost exploded. I'm sure if I took a couple hours and learned the syntax, it'd make (more) sense.

Comment: I was just about to explain the difference between lists (collections) and arrays, too.  You beat me to it!  I was going to suggest creating a class to store the data too, but he is trying to make a method that can execute any query and return the results.  I would personally never do that, and would suggest making separate methods for each query, as you are suggesting.  However, if he needs it to be able to run any query, I would suggest using a DataTable or DataSet rather than a 2D array.

Comment: @SteveDog still, whatever he can do with an array, he can manage with a list. May have to tweak some things here and there, but it doesn't sound like he's too far along with the VB anyway. Dynamic SQL strings are rarely a good idea. =|

Comment: Agreed.  I very rarely ever use arrays.  I use List(Of) for most things because it's just easier to work with.